# Using Linq to select x amount of objects from an observable collection

Tags: c#, linq

I am sure this can be done I just haven't figured it out,

I have an observable collection right? lets say it has 6 objects... Then, based on a particular object I need to select all the objects up to the currently selected object, i.e. if my currently selected object is three I want to pull out one, two, and three and forget the rest...

I was trying to figure out how to do that with Linq but I couldn't, any wizards out there that can show me the light? I probably know how but just can't connect the dots.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `.TakeWhile()`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Take` extension method. It allows you to essentially "take" x amount of elements starting with the zero'th element from your collection.

```
myCollection.Take(3);
```

Comment: Different than what he was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
breadCrumbsMenuItems.TakeWhile(item => !item.Name.Equals(menuItemViewModel.Name));
```